# rspec capybara tests only showing "data:," in chrome then failing with EOFError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rspec, capybara

Our rspec feature specs that use capybara and chromedriver run fine locally on my mac or in my vagrant Ubuntu environment.
Until recently they also worked fine on my Ubuntu machine (16.04).
However a couple of weeks ago they 'broke' and now I get EOFError: end of file reached.  However this message is misleading becuase the same code, master branch, up-to-date works in the other 2 environments I mentioned.
What could be causing this?

I have:

- updated my Ubuntu software to be up-do-date
- make sure the code is the same
- tried switching to an older commit from months ago that I *know* worked before*

* this tells me it must be something outside of my rails code and environment.  Maybe a chrome change for the ubuntu executable?  not sure.

Comment: Make sure chromedriver is updated

Comment: I updated chromedriver to the latest version 2.23.409687 but it didn't help :(

Comment: The latest chromedriver is 2.27. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: YES that worked!!!!  Ah yes I didn't unpack and copy correctly.  Please post comment as answer and I will accept.

Comment: Would be good to put this in the answer: you can use your browser to download and unzip or do it at the command line.  Either way, copy the executable to `/usr/local/bin`.  You can use `chromedriver -v` to verify you have the latest version.

Comment: fyi, one thing I'm observing is that it seems significantly slower.  This might be a side effect of fixing timing bugs that cuase intermittent errors but that is pure speculation from me.  Watch our for increased run times but fixes to intermittent failures that might make the increase worth it.  So don't just switch to firefox in frustration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update chromedriver to the latest version - 2.27 currently